# What should be set in the oracle home of PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

Oracle client is installed in the path `D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1`.

What should be set in the oracle home of PL/SQL DEVELOPER?

[image]

Comment: Isn't auto-detect finding it? Do you have multiple client/server installations on the same machine and you're trying tp pick a specific one?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ORACLE_BASE=D:\oracle
 ORACLE_HOME=D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1
```

This is pattern for BASE and HOME

BASE is where the ORACLE is installed and HOME is directory, where You have f.e. bin, network etc. so \version\client or dbhome_x

Comment: Thanks Michal,I have set the oracle_home as D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1 and  oci library as D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN\oci.dll,but when I try to login I am getting emtpy error message.